# How does a minimal proxy look like in Solidity code?

Tags: solidity, proxy-contracts

I have been using minimal proxy and I understand how it works. However, I would like to know how it looks like in Solidity as I plan to make some slight modifications to it while wanting to keep it as small as it is and remain safe to use.

Does a minimal proxy solidity code going to a contract with a delegate function? Something like this?

```
contract MinimalProxy {
  address internal constant impl = 0xabcd;

  // From OpenZeppelin's Proxy contract
  function _delegate(address implementation) internal virtual {
        assembly {
            // Copy msg.data. We take full control of memory in this inline assembly
            // block because it will not return to Solidity code. We overwrite the
            // Solidity scratch pad at memory position 0.
            calldatacopy(0, 0, calldatasize())

            // Call the implementation.
            // out and outsize are 0 because we don't know the size yet.
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), implementation, 0, calldatasize(), 0, 0)

            // Copy the returned data.
            returndatacopy(0, 0, returndatasize())

            switch result
            // delegatecall returns 0 on error.
            case 0 {
                revert(0, returndatasize())
            }
            default {
                return(0, returndatasize())
            }
        }
    }

  fallback() external payable virtual {
    _delegate(_impl);
  }
}
```

When I tried to compile this, it looks larger than what the usual minimal proxy bytecode is. How should a minimal proxy look like in Solidity code?

Answer (score 0):

Basically there! EIP-1167 had the minimal one, but I don't know if it's achievable with this solidity pattern. Take a look: https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1167

Comment: But the page doesn't have the Solidity version of the minimal proxy, only the bytecode of it. I wanted to see how the bytecodes would look in solidity.

Comment: Nope, not possible unfortunately, this goes into it a little bit, but you can see the bytecode of the minimal contract (since its created and not deployed) looks really different.  https://blog.openzeppelin.com/deep-dive-into-the-minimal-proxy-contract/

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, creating a [mini proxy](https://miniproxy.net/?fbclid=IwAR2gShQ2UnkwB_tmU1ruMrgvxTIwEa3ZPqDj1T4CLtNYldRCFQpqjseqBoE) that [works](https://forum.gl-inet.com/t/set-shadowsocks-and-ssh-proxy-in-gl-inet-gl-mt300n-v2-mini-travel-router/5771) involves using the `CREATE2` opcode to deploy a new contract that delegates all calls to an existing contract. Below is a simple example of a minimal proxy contract in Solidity:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MinimalProxy {
    address public target;

    constructor(address _target) {
        target = _target;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        assembly {
            // Copy the data sent to the proxy to memory
            let ptr := mload(0x40)
            calldatacopy(ptr, 0, calldatasize())

            // Delegatecall to the target contract with the copied calldata
            let result := delegatecall(gas(), sload(target.slot), ptr, calldatasize(), 0, 0)

            // Propagate any returned data
            let size := returndatasize()
            returndatacopy(ptr, 0, size)

            // Revert if the call to the target reverted
            if iszero(result) {
                revert(ptr, size)
            }

            // Return the result of the delegatecall
            return(ptr, size)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your latest edits look suspicious. Why are you linking to those sites? What is the significance of the long unique identifier in the URL?